# Get Variants in Picklist - Big commerce

Tags: product, bigcommerce, modifier, picklist

I have a Bigcommerce store where we have products with variants.
Different component parts are available in different colour and sizes and can be put together to build a product that's what I wanted to achieve.

As Bigcommerce doesn't allow to put variants by default in the shared modifier -> picklist just wondering how I can achieve this.

Any help/guidance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Picklists](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Product-Options-v3?language=en_US#picklist) can only be used with products without variants. If there aren't many products then you can consider a flat product structure or else look into apps such as [Kit Builder](https://www.bigcommerce.com/apps/kit-builder/) or [Bundle Buddy](https://www.bigcommerce.com/apps/integer-bundle-buddy/) to see if it can suit your requirements.